# Respons for request always returns GET

Tags: rest, api, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have Codeigniter 3 and I'm building own API REST (without any external libraries). Everything is working except one thing. When I make request in POSTMAN program as `POST`, `PUT` or `DELETE` Codeigniter always recognizes it as `GET` (`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` return me `GET`). How can I config Codeigniter to handle types `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`? My Codeigniter is working on `HTTPS`. In .htaccess I have

`<Limit PUT DELETE>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Limit>`

**SOLUTION**

There was problem with redirection in HOOK. `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD']` solves problem.

Answer (score 0):

can you trye the code bellow:

```
<LIMIT PUT DELETE OPTIONS PATCH>
  order allow,deny
  allow from all
</LIMIT>
```

and you must also autorise others applications to use your API and allow all verbs in your frontal controller or in your specify controler of each access points:

```
class Rest_controller extends REST_Controller
{
    public function __construct($config = 'rest')
    {
        parent::__construct($config);

        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    }
}
```

Comment: It still does not work. Can the problem be in routes or in other .htaccess confgurations?

Comment: `xxxxxxxxxx - - [05/Aug/2019:22:23:43 +0200] "GET /rest/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 67 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2"
xxxxxxxxxx - - [05/Aug/2019:22:24:01 +0200] "POST /rest/ping HTTP/1.1" 400 67 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2"
xxxxxxxxxx - - [05/Aug/2019:22:24:57 +0200] "DELETE /rest/ping HTTP/1.1" 400 67 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2"
xxxxxxxxxx- - [05/Aug/2019:22:25:22 +0200] "PUT /rest/ping HTTP/1.1" 400 67 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2"`

But `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` always see GET

Comment: I checked `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` in single PHP file and it works - it response `POST GET PUT DELETE` so problem is in CodeIgniter configuration but i don't have idea where.